# How do I check if an element is present in selenium (python 2) without throwing a NoSuchElement Exception if it isn't?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to check whether an element is present on the page I am testing but I don't want the find_element_by_xpath function to throw a NoSuchElement Exception if it isn't present.  Here's my current code:

```
try:
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(an_element)

    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(another_element)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        ... (If the first find_element works and second doesn't I want this code)

except NoSuchElementException:
    ... (If the first find_element fails I want this code)
```

This is essentially functioning as an if else statement so I would prefer to use an if else statement so that I could find a different no such element exception within these code blocks.

Is there another option other that doesn't throw an exception if the element is not present?

## EDIT:

The answers given work great! Thanks to those who answered.  I also figured out another way if you're reading this with the same problem:

When you use find_element**s**_by_xpath() it returns a list of elements found.  If this list has a length of 0 then the element is not present.  If length is 1 element is present.  No exception thrown.

Comment: What you are describing in your question as what you chose as an answer is basically Andersson's answer. If that's actually what you went with, you should accept his answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search into page_source, where there are all html tags and content :

```
if '<button class="">' in self.driver.page_source:
    ... (do one thing)
else:
    ... (do another thing)
```

Comment: This might work but the element I'm searching for doesn't have any text.  I'm trying to search for a list of buttons that is present depending on the amount of results a search yields

Comment: If you are using this method, you are skipping all the functionality of Selenium and doing straight string parsing. It's going to be very brittle because of the exact string match. If the HTML of that button changes in any way (even an extra space somewhere), the string match will fail and the script will proceed as if the button is not there. It's better to use the method Andersson describes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code:

```
if self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(an_element):
    if self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(another_element):
        # code for case both found
    else:
        # second not found
else:
    # first not found
```

Note that `find_elements_by_xpath()` returns you list of WebElements or empty list. No need to handle `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Yeah, this answer is probably better than mine, just don't forget the `s` at `elements`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is exactly correct for doing this kind of thing. In Python, try/except is a valid control structure to use like this and is often (almost always) more efficient than using an if/else block. You may also want to simplify your code by splitting it up into different functions, like the example below (in response to edit).

```
class SomeClass(object):
    """Your class which is doing the scraping"""

    def find_element(self, xpath):
        """A handy function to try and find the element.

        Args:
            xpath (str): the xpath string you are trying to find

        Returns:
            List of elements
        """
        try:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return []

    def find_buttons(self):
        """method to find your buttons

        Returns:
            list of buttons, or empty list if no buttons found
        """
        # define your queries
        xpaths = ['/some/query', '/some/other/query']

        # iterate through them
        for xpath in xpaths:
            buttons = self.find_element(xpath)
            if buttons:
                # until you are successful 
                return buttons

        # or return empty list if no buttons found
        return []
```

Comment: Sandy Leach, page_source is also html tags so you can do : `if '<button class="bootstrap bullshit">' in self.driver.page_source:`

Comment: You can definitely write an xpath query to do that (regardless of whether it has text in it or not), but that's not really in the scope of the question as it stands at the moment. In the event that there are 0 buttons found by your query (i.e., no more results), then catching the `NoSuchElement` exception is a pythonic way of handling that case.

Comment: The problem is for the code under the try I need to be able to try and except another find_element().  If I leave it as is when I get a no such found element exception it does to the first except and executes the  code "do another thing" which is not what I want.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question with a more detailed example of the problem?

Comment: I tried updating the code a bit so you can see my problem

Comment: @AntoineLB I'm trying your code I think this is exactly what I want

Comment: Thank you both! Very helpful